# No fractional scaling option for displays with Cinnamon 5.11.0-43-generic

Tags: 20.04, cinnamon

I recently changed from GNOME to Cinnamon 5.11 for my desktop environment. However, I'm not seeing any option for fractional scaling of my displays in the GUI. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVk9o.jpg. The only options under "User interface scaling" that I see are "Automatic", "Normal", and "Double". I'd like to be able to apply different scaling to each display. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Different desktop environments have different options/settings.

Comment: GNOME (GTK3/4) & KDE (Qt5) give users the most control